# Ad hoc doesn't appear in iTunes

Tags: iphone, xcode, itunes, ios4

I've updated a 3.x app to sdk4.  I have iOS4 installed on my phone.  I drop the Ad Hoc version of the app into iTunes.  It prompts to replace the provisioning profile and I click yes.  Then  I don't see the app in iTunes.  I do have the iTunesArtwork file in the resources folder.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

I'm running Xcode 3.2.3 and latest non beta sdk (4).

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when in your projects .plist file you have the

> Application requires iPhone
>   environment

set as false.

**Check the checkbox** along the above key (enter it verbatim if it's by some means not present there)

Should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you mean info.plist?  I don't see that option in the drop down.